# How to generate dynamically multiple div sets with classess

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've got this table; 10 rows, 25 columns each. Those 25 columns use approx. 11 classes. Rows have altering background, so it's additional 2 classes.
And I need to generate that dynamically with jQuery.
I'm using `getJSON` to extract data from JSON and bind it to the divs.

That's the script I use to bind JSON to divs

```
function getJSON(){
    $.getJSON('url', function(json){
        if (json != null){
            var variable = json[0]["scope"];
            processVariable(variable);
        }
    });
}
function processVariable(variable) {
    variable.forEach(function(varia){
        $(".className-" + varia["jsonID"]).html(varia["value"]);
    });
}

getJSON();
```

(Script is working fine and I'm happy with it; Including it only so You know what's happening).

And now I need to generate dynamically those divs. Tried to hardcode it, but in a long run I want something different.

I was thinking about iterating trough `var variable` to determine how many rows will I need and then generate div after div for each row (maybe `$('<div/>', {class: '$(".className-" + varia["jsonID"]);`), but I have nos slightest idea how to get about it. 
Any and all advice is gold :)

Comment: The best way to dynamically generate elements and append in the body is to use **Document Fragments** https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Can you explain better your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
function processVariable(variable) {
    variable.forEach(function(varia){
        $('<div/>').addClass(".className-" + varia["jsonID"]).html(varia["value"]).appendTo('body');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This way should be done:

```
function processVariable(variable) {
    variable.forEach(function(varia){
        $("<div/>", {
            class:"className-" + varia["jsonID"],
            html:varia["value"]
        }).appendTo(document.body); // or any target element
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But I was thinking, maybe there is a way to keep divs hardcoded; Problem is with the way I did my function, if I copy the whole row, I would also copy the JSON binds, so I have two (or more) exact same rows. Originally I wanted to go with `classname[i].innerHTML = json[i]["jsonID"]` which would allow me to  go trough JSON easily, but for various reasons I had to do it the way I did. So I was thinking - if I could somehow append the ["jsonID"] in classname (maybe change classname to na id) and continue same iteration through consecutive rows... Is it possible even?